# Definition of Integrable Functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, definition, intuition

I am following Folland to study integration theory. It seems like we are restricted to consider only measurable functions such that $\int_X |f| \,d\mu < +\infty$ as integrable. However, Folland also mentioned that the definition
$\int_X f\,d\mu := \int_X f^+ \,d\mu - \int_X f^- \,d\mu$ is well-defined for either $\int_X f^+ \,d\mu < +\infty$ or $\int_X f^- \,d\mu < +\infty$.

My question is: What desirable result would fail if we defined integrable function not as "absolutely integrable", but as the later definition for measurable functions such that either $\int_X f^+ \,d\mu < +\infty$ or $\int_X f^- \,d\mu < +\infty$? It seems natural, at least at first glance, to define integrable function as in the later sense and allow infinite integrals to happen.

I can start off with a simple one: If a function $f_1, f_2: X \to \mathbf{R}$ are integrable in the later sense, then it is not necessarily true that $f_1 + f_2: X \to \mathbf{R}$ is integrable and so we do not have $\int_X f_1 + f_2 \,d\mu$ as $\int_X f_1 \,d\mu + \int_X f_2 \,d\mu$.

Comment: A classic example is $\int_0^\infty {\sin x\over x}\;dx$. A sort of "conditionally, but not absolutely, convergent" integral... The usual "definitions" of Lebesgue integrals would declare this _not_ L-integrable, but, meanwhile, the usual "definitions" of Riemann integrals can make sense of it. This is a traditional prankish (in my opinion!) issue about the distinction... The reason I call it prankish is that it's just a test on literal definitions, and not really about mathematical substance. Conventions versus reality.

Comment: @paulgarrett Great example! I am curious: We are, in some sense, looking for a "better" integration system, right? Now it seems like it's just better in terms of convergence results and we are able to integrate a larger class of functions. However, we also lose some of the functions that we were able to integrate using Riemann integrals. Why would this not cause a problem?

Comment: Well, yes, a strict adoption of "the new definitions" does create some problems that did not exist before, while solving others. :)  The lesson I've taken from this sort of thing is that it is quite difficult to completely formalize "useful mathematics"... but/and maybe it's not absolutely necessary to do so? :)

Comment: The Lebesgue integral on a compact interval $[a,b]$ includes the Riemann integral but does not include the improper Riemann integral that you learned in the calculus.  It is easy to give an example of a differentiable function $F$ such that $F'=f$ is improperly Riemann integrable but $\int_a^b f^+(x)\,dx=\int_a^b f^-(x)\,dx= \infty$ in the sense of the Lebesgue integral.  There are other "nonabsolute integrals" that you can study, even though the Lebesgue integral is the most important tool for most situations.

Comment: The ideology behind the Lebesgue integral is that we should be agnostic about "starting points" and "ending points" when talking about area. The Riemann approach *imposes* meaning to $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} \ dx$ by declaring the origin more valuable than other parts of the domain. From the Lebesgue standpoint this is arbitrary and incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folland's version is standard for integrals defined by measure theory.

1. Define
   $$\int_X f\,d\mu := \int_X f^+ \,d\mu - \int_X f^- \,d\mu $$
   and declare $f$ *integrable* if both are finite.
2. If only one of those integrals is infinite, **do not say that $f$ is integrable** but write this anyway:
   $$\int_X f\,d\mu := \int_X f^+ \,d\mu - \int_X f^- \,d\mu$$
   allowing values $+\infty$ and $-\infty$.
3. If $ \int_X f^+ \,d\mu = \int_X f^- \,d\mu =\infty$ do not say anything and do not use the expression $\int_X f\,d\mu$ since (in measure theory) it cannot be assigned any meaningful value.

For purposes of exposition this allows a nice theory for integrable functions, and it allows many theorems for nonintegrable functions to be stated with infinite integrals.  Most good theorems will be stated for integrable functions.  With some caution you can still use the infinite valued integral, but be careful.  It is not worth fussing too much, just don't be seduced into false statements.

In case #3 there is no theory?  Well in many cases there is, but it is outside measure theory.

Restrict attention to the real line.  Now this is Lebesgue's classical theory, except he originally called "integrable" functions "summable" probably so as not to conflict with Riemann integrability.

Is there any interest in functions  $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ for which
$$\int_a^b f^+(x)\,dx =\int_a^b f^-(x)\,dx =\infty$$
which is case #3 above (ignored by measure theory and by Lebesgue's original integral)?

The problem that Lebesgue gave as his motivation was to find an integral that handled all derivatives and included the Riemann integral.  The Riemann integral does not integrate all derivatives.

Unfortunately neither does Lebesgue's integral.  I gather this annoyed him.  It handled all bounded derivatives and includes the Riemann integral.

But "most" derivatives are like this:  $F'(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in [a,b]$ but
$$\int_a^b f^+(x)\,dx =\int_a^b f^-(x)\,dx =\infty.$$

So very sorry.  Cannot integrate derivatives.  But Newton and Leibnitz could (albeit trivially).  Why isn't
$$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx =F(b)-F(a)?$$

Apologize.  Sheepishly say, the Lebesgue integral wasn't designed for that.  Or develop an entirely different method of integration that is not based on measure theory.

That was done about ten years after Lebesgue's integral by a German mathematician Perron and a French mathematician Denjoy.  Their integral includes the Lebesgue integral and integrates all derivatives.  So you might say their integration method explores the case #3 above that measure theory refuses to address.

The story continues.  A trigonometric series can converge everywhere to a function that is not Lebesgue integrable (or even Denjoy-Perron integrable).  Ideally you would want to compute the coefficients using the Fourier formulas---but what integral can you use?  Time for another "nonabsolutely convergent integral" that lives in the same crack left by #3.

Want more?  Probably not, but there are more.

The short answer is that the case #3 that measure theory and Lebesgue himself abandonned can be explored by other methods suitable to the situation.  But measure theory is designed to leave that case alone.  But the situations #1 and #2 cover most interesting and important applications anyway, so not a lot is lost.

Comment: Thank you for your insight! I know that $L^1$ function, i.e. case 1, can induce a signed measure. However, as we lost the basic property of even adding functions for integration in case 2, we can no longer conclude that those functions in case 2 would induce a signed measure anymore, is this correct? Namely, we can't even split up integration domains into disjoint pieces if we were dealing with case 2.

Comment: @Mathematics_Beginner  In case #2 you can define $\nu(E)=\int_E f\,d\mu$ for each measurable set $E$.  That will be a signed measure (just not a finite valued one).  Also $\nu=\nu_1-\nu_2$ where $\nu_1(E)=\int_E f^+\,d\mu$ and $\nu_2(E)=\int_E f^-\,d\mu$.  In fact any signed measure is the difference of two measures one of which must be finite.  See Theorem 2.23 (Jordan decomposition) in http://classicalrealanalysis.info/documents/BBT-AlllChapters-Landscape.pdf